# error 400 Bad Request - Retrofit

Tags: android, bad-request

Everything works fine for some time. After some usage of the app,with every api hit, it starts giving this repsonse, for all apis.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
    <html><head>
    <title>400 Bad Request</title>
    </head><body>
    <h1>Bad Request</h1>
    <p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<br />
    The number of request header fields exceeds this server's limit.</p>
     </body></html>
```

How do i fix it from app side or server side ? Don't know the cause of this response.

Comment: I really bet, that it's server side

Comment: seems like it, but i have least knowledge of server side.

Comment: how do you attach headers?

Comment: it's a post request without any headers.

Comment: @Bawa did you able to find any workaround?

Comment: @android_griezmann - no, i was not able to find a solution. Not working on the same project anymore.

Comment: @Bawa humm weird error though!

Comment: @android_griezmann yes, please let me know if you find a solution.